# @Resource on type level

Tags: java, spring, jsr

I found @Resource can also be applied at class level:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncjk.html

> Class-Based Injection To use class-based injection, decorate the class
>   with a @Resource annotation, and set the required name and type
>   elements.
>
> @Resource(name="myMessageQueue",
>                   type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory") 
>                              public class SomeMessageBean { ... }

Do you have any experience using @Resource this way?

Comment: do you have a more specific question?

Comment: What does Resource do when applied at type level? I know you can autowire by name when you place Resource on a field or method level, but how about type? Can you combine it with other annotations (also Resource or other). There is a lot of information about @Resource, but I cant find any example of using it on a class level. I tried to examine this piece of code but I doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

From Resource javadoc

> The Resource annotation marks a resource that is needed by the
>   application.  This annotation may be applied to an application
>   component class, or to fields or methods of the component class. 
>   When the annotation is applied to a field or method, the container
>   will inject an instance of the requested resource into the
>   application component when the component is initialized.  **If the
>   annotation is applied to the component class, the annotation
>   declares a resource that the application will look up at runtime**

This means that the class annotated with @Resource at class level will be considered as candidates for auto-detection when using annotation-based configuration and classpath scanning